# Couldn't insert into Database: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table in hte same database similar to this that has no difference in syntax or format. Yet I get the above mentioned error? I have done everything I know to fix it, but not sure what I have done wrong. I have an image of the structure as well.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `FormInfo` (`first_name`, 
                                `last_name`, 
                                `company`, 
                                `address`, 
                                `province`, 
                                `postal`, 
                                `telephone`, 
                                `fax`, 
                                `email`, 
                                `comment`) 
                        VALUES ('$good_data[first_name]',
                                '$good_data[last_name]',
                                '$good_data[company]',
                                '$good_data[address]',
                                '$good_data[province]',
                                '$good_data[postal]',
                                '$good_data[telephone]',
                                '$good_data[email]',
                                '$good_data[comment]')";
mysqli_query($cxn, $sql) or die ("Couldn't insert into Database: " . mysqli_error($cxn));
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your values statement only has 9 columns listed, while the insert is specifying 10

Comment: right!! whoops!! ok thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your `$good_data[fax]` argument

EDIT: Also, please consider the way you are calling your objects in your array is bad practice. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more information

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `FormInfo` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `company`, `address`, `province`, `postal`, `telephone`, `fax`, `email` ,`comment`) VALUES ('$good_data[first_name]', '$good_data[last_name]', '$good_data[company]', '$good_data[address]', '$good_data[province]', '$good_data[postal]', '$good_data[telephone]', '$good_data[email]', '$good_data[comment]')";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `FormInfo` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `company`, `address`, `province`, `postal`, `telephone`, `fax`, `email` ,`comment`) VALUES ('$good_data[first_name]', '$good_data[last_name]', '$good_data[company]', '$good_data[address]', '$good_data[province]', '$good_data[postal]', '$good_data[telephone]', '$good_data[email]', '$good_data[comment]', '$good_data[fax]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing insert value for `fax` column:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO `FormInfo` 
       (`first_name`, 
      `last_name`,
       `company`, 
       `address`, 
       `province`, 
       `postal`, 
       `telephone`, 
       `fax`, 
       `email`,
       `comment`
       ) 
      VALUES (
      '$good_data[first_name]', 
      '$good_data[last_name]', 
      '$good_data[company]', 
      '$good_data[address]', 
      '$good_data[province]', 
      '$good_data[postal]', 
      '$good_data[telephone]', 
      '$good_data[fax]',   
      '$good_data[email]', 
      '$good_data[comment]'
      )";
```